# Azure app cannot connect to Azure Suse VM on the same location

Tags: mysql, azure, suse

I have an Azure app that connects to a MySQL database installed on a Suse virtual machine on the same Azure location as the app. It happens that this connection goes on and off, intermittently. The Azure app works fine with databases located outside Azure and I can connect with the VM and its databases from outside Azure. Any ideas about the reason?